# Error with AVAudioRecorder record

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, avfoundation, avaudiorecorder

I'm getting this error

```
*** -[CFDictionary objectForKey:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x82a2730
```

when I try to start the recorder after stopping it.

This is what I get when I do bt:

```
#0  0x00b49e1e in ___forwarding___ ()
#1  0x00b49ce2 in __forwarding_prep_0___ ()
#2  0x00d91223 in getUInt32ForKey ()
#3  0x00d928a6 in prepareToRecordQueue () 
#4  0x00d93023 in recordQueue ()
#5  0x00d91d03 in -[AVAudioRecorder record] ()
```

Comment: I think you are releasing some object when you stop the recording. and after that when you try to record again it causes the crash.

Comment: please explain it in more details with step by step code so that one can understand what you want to do.

Comment: I'm recording my voice with [avrecorder record]. When I stop the recorder with [avrecorder stop], I'm showing a View which let me make different options. When I dismiss that view, I call [avrecorder record] again for starting the same process, but I'm getting the error of my answer. I'm not releasing anything of the avrecorder, just stopping and recording.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! My mistake, I was releasing wrongly the settings of the audiorecorder!! :-O

NSDictionary *recordSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:...];
theAudioRecorder_ = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:soundFileUrl 
                                                settings:recordSettings 
                                                   error:nil];

**[recordSettings release];**